# TS 4.8 Unhandled SyntaxKind: ImportClause

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I am trying to update ts version from 3.9.x to latest, there are no issues if update to 4.7.4 or earlier, but 4.8.x version throws an error while compiling.
Error: `Unhandled SyntaxKind: ImportClause`

Apart from that this is the error info, I cannot track the file name where the issue is being raised, is there any way I can debug this better. I tried logging in node modules package itself found the source file object not sure if that is the source of the error.

```
src/index.ts → dist/index.js...
DeprecationWarning: 'createLiteral' has been deprecated since v4.0.0. Use `factory.createStringLiteral`, `factory.createStringLiteralFromNode`, `factory.createNumericLiteral`, `factory.createBigIntLiteral`, `factory.createTrue`, `factory.createFalse`, or the factory supplied by your transformation context instead.
DeprecationWarning: 'updateImportDeclaration' has been deprecated since v4.0.0. Use the appropriate method on 'ts.factory' or the 'factory' supplied by your transformation context instead.
DeprecationWarning: 'createLiteralTypeNode' has been deprecated since v4.0.0. Use the appropriate method on 'ts.factory' or the 'factory' supplied by your transformation context instead.
DeprecationWarning: 'updateImportTypeNode' has been deprecated since v4.0.0. Use the appropriate method on 'ts.factory' or the 'factory' supplied by your transformation context instead.
/<path>/<package>/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:119204
                throw e;
                ^

Error: Debug Failure. Unhandled SyntaxKind: ImportClause.
    at pipelineEmitWithHintWorker (/<path>/<package>/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:113127:22)
    at pipelineEmitWithHint (/<path>/<package>/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:112660:17)
    at pipelineEmitWithComments (/<path>/<package>/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:116301:13)
    at pipelineEmit (/<path>/<package>/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:112600:13)
    at emitExpression (/<path>/<package>/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:112584:13)
    at emitImportDeclaration (/<path>/<package>/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:114544:13)
    at pipelineEmitWithHintWorker (/<path>/<package>/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:112861:32)
    at pipelineEmitWithHint (/<path>/<package>/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:112660:17)
    at pipelineEmitWithComments (/<path>/<package>/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:116301:13)
    at pipelineEmit (/<path>/<package>/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:112600:13)
```

Comment: did you found a solution with this issue?